# Tooltip button in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

Is there a way for creating a tooltip button in a Chrome extension that will appear when text is selected?

Something similar with Opera browser's: https://forums.opera.com/assets/uploads/files/1588929597360-select.png Search and Copy buttons.

I'm checking the API, but I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: This is standard DOM, no such API. Add a listener for `selectionchange` event (in your content script) that inserts an absolutely positioned DOM element with your UI.

Comment: @wOxxOm
Is there a way to detect a click outside the tooltip? I'm using the mousedown event for hiding the tooltip, but I have a problem. If I click on the button, the click closes the tooltip, but the button itself is not clicked nor the action associated with it is executed.
If I delete the function that closes the tooltip (and I don't detect the mousedown event), clicking on the button works fine, but obviously I can't close the tooltip in that case.

Comment: @wOxxOm
Never mind, I found a workaround. I close the tooltip on mousedown when clicking outside and on mouseup when clicking inside. The mouseup event allows the button to get pressed and execute its actions.